# Mono Gtk Window require focus for input

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

I haven't been able to find an example containing this functionality, and either i missed it in the documentation or it's not there.

I have a **fullscreen GUI program**, and when a user is required to type in a number, a calculator window popup has to appear in the center of the screen.  The user types a number and clicks on enter, or hits cancel to continue past the window.

The problem is **clicking on the fullscreen window behind the calculator brings that window to the front and hides the calculator without the intended entry being completed, which could get annoying for the user**.

I guess the functionality I'm trying to create is what happens in most text editors/IDE's when you press the Open File button.  Let me know if you want to see code, it's just two separate Window classes at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Amith003, but it seems I've stumbled upon the answer to my own question.

I can't answer my own question for 6 more hours so I'll post it here for now.

    calculator.calc.FocusOutEvent += (obj, args) => calculator.calc.Present();

Where calculator is my custom class and calc is the public Window attribute.  When focus leaves the calculator window it triggers the FocusOutEvent and eventually calls Present() on the window, bringing it to the forefront of the screen.  Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: Sounds like you just want a modal dialog? See [Window.Modal](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=P%3aGtk.Window.Modal)

Comment: Yep, looking back I should have known that, couldn't remember the term "modal".  Add it as an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Present() function of the Window object brings that particular window to the front.  So adding a FocusOutEvent listener on the window you wish to keep in front like:

```
windowObj.FocusOutEvent += (obj, args) => windowObj.Present();
```

will work.

The alternative to this (and the better way) is to set the Modal property of the window to true.

If you've stumbled across this and you were looking for a popup window that suspends whatever called it to wait for input, see this question:

[gtk# thread for window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19714214/gtk-thread-for-window)

You basically use the Dialog class instead of Window and add your elements to the ActionArea of the Dialog.

Hope this helps.